# Rectangle behaving strangely within rotated scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my minimal example :

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[text=black,text centered,text width=1.5cm]

        \def \n {5}
        \def \radius {3cm}
        \node[circle, draw] (c) at (0, 0) {C};

        \foreach \s in {1,...,\n} {

            \begin{scope}[shift={({-(360/\n * (\s-1)) + 90}:\radius)},rotate={-360/\n*(\s-1)}]
                \node[] (id) at (0, 4) {Id : \s};
                \node[circle, draw] (a) at (0, 3) {A};
                \node[circle, draw] (b) at (0, 0) {B};
                \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
                \draw[->] (b) -- (c);
                \draw[thick] ($(id.north west)+(-0.6,0.6)$)  rectangle ($(b.south east)+(0.6,-0.6)$);
            \end{scope}

        }

      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I create three nodes, draw a box around them and rotate this drawing by an angle. My problem is that the coordinates of the rectangle seem to be calculated after the rotation occurred which should not happen.

[image]

As a side note, is it possible to rotate the text in the (id) nodes?

[EDIT] For the rotation of the text, I just added my `rotate=...` to the node and it works perfectly.

Comment: You need to add `transform shape` here `\begin{scope}[shift={({-(360/\n * (\s-1)) + 90}:\radius)},rotate={-360/\n*(\s-1)},transform shape]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `nodes` are insensitive to transformations. For them to apply, it is necessary to add the `tranform shape` option.

I quote the TikZ 3.1.4b manual:

> **17.7 Transformations**
>
> It is possible to transform nodes, but, by default, transformations do not apply to nodes. The reason is that you
>   usually do *not* want your text to be scaled or rotated even if the main
>   graphic is transformed. Scaling text is evil, rotating slightly less
>   so. However, sometimes you do wish to transform a node, for example,
>   it certainly sometimes makes sense to rotate a node by 90 degrees

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[text=black,text centered,text width=1.5cm]

        \def \n {5}
        \def \radius {3cm}
        \node[circle, draw] (c) at (0, 0) {C};

        \foreach \s in {1,...,\n} {

            \begin{scope}[shift={({-(360/\n * (\s-1)) + 90}:\radius)},rotate={-360/\n*(\s-1)},transform shape]
                \node[] (id) at (0, 4) {Id : \s};
                \node[circle, draw] (a) at (0, 3) {A};
                \node[circle, draw] (b) at (0, 0) {B};
                \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
                \draw[->] (b) -- (c);
                \draw[thick] ($(id.north west)+(-0.6,0.6)$)  rectangle ($(b.south east)+(0.6,-0.6)$);
            \end{scope}

        }

      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Love you. Thanks. Sad thing is it rotates the text in the nodes too...

Comment: It is possible to rotate the text in the opposite direction so that the text does not rotate.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, thanks ;-)

Comment: By the way, would you happen to know how to define, for example `\def \nm {\n-1}` where `\nm` would be equal to 4 in my case?

Comment: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\nm}{\n-1}` would be the solution, I guess?

Comment: It's one way to do it, but not the only way.

Answer (score 3):

An another approach:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=\radius, sloped},
R/.style = {draw, minimum height=\radius+2mm, minimum width=3*\radius+3mm,
             rotate=\ang, right}
                    ]

\def\n{5}
\def\radius {7mm}
\node (c) [C] {C};
%
\foreach \i [count=\s from 0] in {1,...,\n}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{90+\s*360/\n}
\draw[<-] (c) -- node[C] {B} ++ (\ang:22mm)
              -- node [C, near end] {A} ++ (\ang:\radius);
\node (r\i) [R] at (\ang:\radius+1mm) {};
\node[rotate=\ang,right] at (r\i.east) {Id=\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have labels of branches aligned with outer lines of rectangles, then you only need to replace last code line with

```
\node[rotate=270+\ang,right, anchor=north] at (r\i.east) {Id=\i};
```

result is shown at example in addendum.

**Adendum:**
 Inspired with comments of @Schrödinger's cat (thank you very much, I learned something new about TikZ) the solution where is used key `rotate fit` . Using it the definition of rectangles become simpler and also autocratically adopt to  position of circle shaped nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=\radius, 
            inner sep=0pt, sloped},
R/.style = {draw, inner sep=1mm, rotate fit=\ang, fit=#1},  % <--- for rotate fit nodes
every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
                    ]

\def\n{5}
\def\radius {7mm}
\node (c) [C] {C};
%
\foreach \i [count=\s from 0] in {1,...,\n}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{90+\s*360/\n}
\path   (c) -- node (c1\i) [C] {B} ++ (\ang:3*\radius)
            -- node (c2\i) [C, at end] {A} ++ (\ang:0.5*\radius);
\draw   (c2\i) edge (c1\i)  (c1\i) edge (c);
\node (r\i) [R=(c1\i)(c2\i)] {}; % <--- "used rotate fit"
\node[rotate=270+\ang,
      right, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize] at (r\i.east) {$\mathrm{Id}=\i$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the foreach with two values, that's a nice thing to know.
It took me some time to understand it and it's a nice method since it allows to be more precise about what to rotate or not. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Since you are loading but not using `fit`: are you looking for the `rotate fit` key?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, ups, tit's the remnant of my failed experiment(s). I will delete it asap. However, I'm interested for such a key (if it exist, I'm not aware about it).

Comment: @Zarko Of course it exists, see p. 678 of pgfmanual v3.1.4b. And it allows you to wrap the rectangle in the way I think you wanted to.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thank you very much for info! Very appreciated. In the first my spare time on evening I will check it and continue with my experiments. However, I will be glad, if you will be willing provide answer using it.

Comment: @Zarko You are welcome! I am not going to write an answer here. `rotate fit` has been used quite a few times on this site (but not nearly as often as `transform shape` has been explained;-), and one of its pitfalls is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504278).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, it is pity (that you not going to answer). Thank you very much for educational  link.

Comment: I'm glad my question allowed to help you find new methods, I learnt a lot from all the answers, actually a bit sad that I can't accept two answers but a big thank ;-)